# VLC sort by track number?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Is there any way to make VLC sort by *track number* as a default when I `Open Directory` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>)?

Comment: Damn this is a great question. I love it when I come back to ask the same thing, in the same fashion and see that I'm treading a path I've already walked.

Answer (score 4):

This is a round about way to do it.

1. Make sure that "Track number" column is visible.

   - Open Directory with CTRL + F so that you have some files displayed.
   - Right mouse click on the column named "Title".
   - It will give you a list, select "Track number"
   - A "Track number" column will be added to the end of the window (you might have to scroll right to see it).
   - You can drag the column headers to where you like them. I put the "Track number" as the second column after the "Title" column and before the "Duration" column
2. Each time you open a directory with VLC you can click on the "Track number" column and it will sort the songs by track order.

Step one only needs to be done once and VLC will remember it each time you open VLC.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easier way to do it, click the "album" order option in the music library. It will automatically order by track number.